# Conditional Formatting in Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to apply a color to a cell's text if the value is not same as a value in another column. What would be the best approach for it ? The way I can think of is quite expensive.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ColumnARange.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (ColumnARange.Cells[i, 1] != ColumnBRange.Cells[i, 1])
                        {
                            Range currCell = ColumnBRange.Cells[i, 1];
                            currCell.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                        }
                    }
```

Tried conditional formatting as below, but in vain.

```
FormatCondition cond = ColumnBRange.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlNotEqual, ColumnARange);
                cond.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

I am using VSTO,C#

Comment: Yes. Need to apply color to cell text by comparing with other column's value. but if I traverse as mentioned in my code, it will be quite expensive considering large data with more rows and columns.

Answer (score 9):

The following code, adds a conditional formatting to the cell range of D1 to E10

It compares the values D1 = E1 or D2 = E2 respectively. you can set the font color, or color fill on the FormatCondition Object.

```
FormatCondition format =(FormatCondition)( targetSheet.get_Range("D1:E10",
                Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
                                                   XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
                                                   "=$D1=$E1", 
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
            
            format.Font.Bold = true;
            format.Font.Color = 0x000000FF;
```

Comment: But how do I handle dynamic ranges ?

Comment: @buffer_overflow check the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=vs.80).aspx) for the declaration of get_range method, you can provide cell 1 n 2 using targetSheet.Cells[1,2] and targetSheet.Cells[3,4] respectively. I hope u gt it

Comment: What if it's just one column duplicates only? Check all of `D1` for example... if two duplicates exist, highlight it.

Comment: You need to change the condition for duplicates in column =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,A1) = 1 where A1 to A10 is your value range.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to color cells `B1:B10` if their values are not equal to those of `A1:A10`, i.e.

`B1<>A1` results in `B1` being colored, `B2<>A2` results in `B2` being colored etc.

Then you can do the following

```
Range columnBRange = (Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1,2], oSheet.Cells[10,2]];

Range columnARange = (Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1,1], oSheet.Cells[1,1]];

FormatCondition cond = (FormatCondition) ColumnBRange.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlNotEqual, "="+ColumnARange.Address[false,true]);
cond.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red); //Red letters
cond.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow); //Light yellow cell background
```

Note that prepending `"="` to `ColumnARange.Address[false,true]` is required because otherwise the `Add` method uses the `Address` as a literal string instead of a cell reference.

If you take look at the conditional formatting rule applied to the `B1:B10` cells in the Excel sheet it will state `Cell Value <> B1` for every cell in the range which is a bit confusing IMO but the formatting is applied correctly nonetheless.

For completeness: I'm using optional objects on `Range.Address` property like so  `Range.Address[isRowAbsolute,isColumnAbsolute]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
FormatCondition cond = ColumnBRange.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlNotEqual, "=$B1");
                cond.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Comment: I've been looking all over for an easy way to pick my colors in VSTO! Thanks!