# EXCEL Conditional Formatting in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have column (excel column: AG) called 'First Price' and a column called 'First Price Override' (excel column: AH) and a column called 'First Price Override 2' (excel column: AI).

I need to write some conditional formatting in C# which checks the values in either column AH or AI. If they have values typed into this cell, the AG column (associated row to the values typed in - need to have a font style strike through set to true)

How do i do this?

```
        var orfirstpricerange1 = Worksheet.Range["AH:AH"];
        var orfirstpricerange2 = Worksheet.Range["AI:AI"];
        var firstpricerange = Worksheet.Range["AG:AG"];

firstpricerange.Font.Strikethrough = true;
```

I have done the above but dont know how to put it together to use conditional formatting.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240132/conditional-formatting-in-excel-with-c-sharp/10241857 ?

Comment: Tried to follow this but I didnt know how to check if the column is an empty cell or has a value in it. The example above shows two columns being equal to eachother. Also the example compares specified rows  - I need to apply this to the entire column. Not just D1 and E1.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //firstpricerange.Font.Strikethrough = true;
```

Above will set the formatting of the complete column to 'Strikethrough'. I have commented it because you do not want to have every cell a strikethrough.

```
    Excel.FormatCondition format = (Excel.FormatCondition)(Worksheet.get_Range("AG:AG",
        Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
        "=AH1=AI1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
    format.Font.Strikethrough = true;
```

'Excel' is referring to `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Currently column AG gets Strikethrough when the value in AH equals the value in AI.

Comment: Hi - this is useful although as per question I am trying to check if there is any value in AH or AI (if true set a strikethrough in the AG row). Looks like the default is setting strike through when there is no value in there. I want it to not strikethrough when no value. and strikethrough when there is a value in either of those columns

Comment: Ok, you should change the formula from `"=AH1=AI1"` to the formula you need it to be. In my Dutch version of excel this is `"=EN(AH1=AI1;NIET(ISLEEG(AH1));NIET(ISLEEG(AI1)))"`, in an English version this should be `"=AND(AH1=AI1,NOT(ISBLANK(AH1)),NOT(ISBLANK(AI1)))"`

Comment: how do you specify the range e.g AG7:AG ? Rather than the whole column? It’s currently applying the strike through on the header column which I don’t want it to do. Any ideas?

Comment: 'AG7:AG' is not a valid range... ?  I was using 'AG:AG' (the complete column),  and in the formula I am only using the first line. This  works for all lines if you just do not use '$' in the cell addresses (unless they need to be fixed).

Comment: I want this conditional formatting to start from AG7 to the end of the column. It seems to be starting from AG1. My header is on AG6 so it is strikethrough on the title. How do i change the C# syntax?

Comment: For Range you will get `AG7:AG5000`  (for 50000 you can use last line which contains data), in the formula you need to change the '1' for a '7', so it will be `"=AH7<>AI7"`  (or whatever you have in your formula) This is because the formula in a conditional formatting always refers to the first line on which the conditional formatting should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition format = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition)(uiWorksheet.get_Range("AG:AG",
  Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlNotEqual,
  "=AH1<>AI1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
        format.Font.Strikethrough = true;
```